# Get messages from Custom properties file

Tags: java, scala, playframework, internationalization, properties-file

I have to create my own custom file, so I created `conf/cred.properties`

> user.group="admin"
>
> user.role="admin"

And how I am getting its value:

```
ConfigFactory.load("cred.properties").getConfig("user").getString("group");
```

Is there any way that I can access:

> group="admin"
>
> role="admin"

from  `cred.properties` file?

I want to remove `user` from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it:

```
ConfigFactory.load("cred.properties").getString("group");
```

But it gives a null pointer exception if it doesn't find key.

Answer (score 0):

Would using a `ResourceBundle` be a good alternative?

```
java.util.ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("conf.cred");
String username = resourceBundle.getString("user.group");
```

Comment: Are you asking or answering here?!